# Visual Basic- Printing sum of user input to a screen

Tags: vb.net

I am finishing up a semester and need some help possibly pointing me in the right direction with the code I currently have.

The program is to generate 2 random numbers and have the end user input a guess at the sum of the 2 numbers. This will loop 10 times and the user will be prompted to give 10 answers. I have no trouble with that part. However, I am unsure how to store the answers and print out to the textbox the number of correct and wrong answers. Here is the code I have currently:

```
Dim elapsed As Double
Dim correct, wrong, add, intRand, intrand2, answer As Integer




Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Randomize()

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click




    'Set randomize range from 0-10


    answer = intRand + intrand2


    For i = 0 To 9

        intRand = Int(Rnd() * (10 + 1)) + 0
        intrand2 = Int(Rnd() * (10 + 1)) + 0



        'Get the answer from the inputbox
        add = InputBox("Add the sum of:" & intRand & "and" & intrand2)

    Next i

    'See if answers are correct, set correct and wrong to 0 and count if answers are correct or incorrect


    correct = 0

    If answer = intRand + intRand Then
        txtOutput.AppendText("Number correct= "(correct + 1))

        correct = answer


        wrong = 0

    ElseIf add <> intRand + intrand2 Then
        txtOutput.AppendText("Number wrong= "(wrong + 1))

        wrong = answer

    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: tag in the questions lists of the followed tags appears as "vba" while this is Vb.net question I think. Don't know if it is question maker or stack overflow's fault. Just as comment

Comment: Thanks my fault. updated

Comment: Well, I think you've got a number of issues going on here, I doubt based on you're description you're going to get anywhere near your required results..  First off, you're setting answer = intRand + intRand2 outside your loop, then testing answer = inRand + intRand.  They will not be equal so unlikely you're ever going to get into the correct part of your if.  Your also reseting the value of wrong, not 100% sure but guessing where your holding you score?  You really need to do some work on debugging.  I would also suggest you probably want to look at variable scope too

Comment: You must get paid by the line. Please use less white space.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the old VB6 random number generator, use the .net Random class. Declare this at Form level. The .Next method will return a number form 1 to 10. It includes the first parameter (1) and excludes the second parameter (11).

Instead of all that code after the loop where you would need to store all the inputs, randoms, and correct answers, just determine the correct answers on each iteration of the loop and increment correct or wrong.

As with all user input, the input must be validated. The .TryParse methods available in .net will do this. The first parameter is a String, the second parameter is a variable to hold the conversion of the string if the conversion is successful. Since our variable is declared as an integer it will be zero (the default value of an Integer) if the conversion fails. In this code that will always be a wrong answer since the range of randoms is 1-10.

For the InputBox and the txtOutput.Text I used an interpolated string indicated by $ preceding the string. Interpolated strings can have variables embedded directly in the string surrounded by braces. Much easier than a bunch of quotes and ampersands. This is available in Visual Studio 2015 and later.

```
Private rand As New Random
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim correct As Integer
    Dim wrong As Integer
    For i = 0 To 9
        Dim intRand = rand.Next(1, 11)
        Dim intRand2 = rand.Next(1, 11)
        Dim correctAnswer = intRand + intRand2
        'Get the answer from the inputbox
        Dim inputAnswer As Integer
        Integer.TryParse(InputBox($"Add the sum of: {intRand} and {intRand2}"), inputAnswer)
        If correctAnswer = inputAnswer Then
            correct += 1
        Else
            wrong += 1
        End If
    Next i

    txtOutput.Text = ($"Number correct= {correct} and the number wrong is {wrong}")

End Sub
```

Be sure you completely understand this code before you turn it in because the teacher will ask you to explain it.